# Screen Won't Light on Startup

Tags: display, power, acer-aspire

I got this Acer Aspire 7714z-4839 from my grandmother just the other day without the original charger. I managed to find a proper power supply to charge it, and after an hour or so, I turned it on. To my dismay, the computer powered on, but the screen didn't. The power supply fan ran for a few seconds and stopped, then started again and the computer would lay there idle with the screen still black. I held a light up to it to see if the backlight had gone out or something from researching similar problems, and nothing was displayed then.

Answer (score 0):

You're not really asking a question.

Try plugging an external monitor into the machine.  If that works then it may be the inverter.   If not, and you're sure the backlight isn't working, then the problem is probably more serious.

Comment: I did, and nothing came up. I'm not sure if the backlight is broken.

Comment: Turn all the lights off in the room.  Turn on the machine.  Does the LCD screen light up at all?  If the backlight is working, you should see some light coming from the display, even if it's just a lit up black screen.